# No me detecta la diagonal en una dirección en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Buen Dia compañeros quisiera saber porque no me aparece la diagonal invertida en JavaScript

Estoy concatenando una dirección con una variable , lo de la variable funciona correctamente pero la dirección no.

```
  var direccion = 'D:\S3\elastianstalk-us-east-2-8\ '
                var filepath = data.key
                DatosServidor(direccion + filepath)  
                console.log(direccion + filepath);
```

y el resultado que obtengo es:

```
D:S3elasticbeanstalk-us-east-2-8 1672.txt
```

Estare muy agradecido si me ayudan , de antemano gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El backslash es un carácter especial en JavaScript, por lo que hay que usarlo siempre escapado, `\\`.

```
var str = "\\Me llamo pepito";
```

Esto se complica un nivel más si uno usa regexp, porque tienes el string de la expresión y otro nivel adicional (para escapar) del analisis de la expresión. Así, debes usar cuatro backslashes para hacer match con UN backslash

```
// Encuentra *un* backslash
var rex = new RegExp("\\\\");
```

A menos que estemos usando el estándar ES2015, donde tenemos la función [String.raw](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-string.raw)

```
let str = String.raw`\pepito`;
```